# Ruby on rails send_data/send_file downloads only latest file on click of multiple records

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, grover

I am running into an issue where only last pdf file is getting downloaded even though I click on multiple records to download parallely.

View

```
<%= link_to(inline_mat_svg :download, stock_item_generate_part_tag_path(stock_item, format: :pdf) %>
```

Controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        pdf = Grover.new("#{request.original_url[0..-5]}?&token=#{@report_user.token}",
                    {format: 'A4',
                      margin: {
                      top: '5px',
                      bottom: '5px',
                      left: '10px',
                      right: '10px'
                     },
                    viewport: {
                    width: 1280,
                    height: 1024
                    },
                    prefer_css_page_size: true,
                    emulate_media: 'screen',
                    # cache: false,
                    timeout: 0, # Timeout in ms. A value of `0` means 'no timeout'
                    launch_args: ['--font-render-hinting=medium'],
                    executable_path: Rails.configuration.chromium_executable_path,
                    wait_until: 'networkidle0'
                  }).to_pdf

 send_data pdf, type: 'application/pdf', filename: "Test_#{Time.now.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')}.pdf", disposition: :attachment
```

**When an user click on multiple records parallely, only last PDf is getting downloaded. But in console multiple PDF files are getting rendered.**

Console:

```
Started GET "/stock_items/502393374/part_tag.pdf" for ::1 at 2020-11-09 19:25:10 -0500
Processing by StockItemsController#part_tag as PDF
  Parameters: {"stock_item_id"=>"502393374"}
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'test.com' LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/concerns/authentication.rb:58:in `in_development_mode?'
  Profile Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `profiles`.* FROM `profiles` WHERE `profiles`.`id` = 185443385 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/models/ability.rb:10:in `block in initialize'
  Permission Load (1.1ms)  SELECT DISTINCT `permissions`.* FROM `permissions` INNER JOIN `permissions_profiles` ON `permissions`.`id` = `permissions_profiles`.`permission_id` WHERE `permissions_profiles`.`profile_id` = 185443385
  ↳ app/models/ability.rb:10:in `block in initialize'
  StockItem Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `stock_items`.* FROM `stock_items` WHERE `stock_items`.`id` = 502393374 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/stock_items_controller.rb:104:in `part_tag'
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'test.com' LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/stock_items_controller.rb:105:in `part_tag'
Started GET "/stock_items/747718251/part_tag.pdf" for ::1 at 2020-11-09 19:25:11 -0500
Processing by StockItemsController#part_tag as PDF
  Parameters: {"stock_item_id"=>"747718251"}
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'abc.com' LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/concerns/authentication.rb:58:in `in_development_mode?'
  Profile Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `profiles`.* FROM `profiles` WHERE `profiles`.`id` = 185443385 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/models/ability.rb:10:in `block in initialize'
  Permission Load (0.8ms)  SELECT DISTINCT `permissions`.* FROM `permissions` INNER JOIN `permissions_profiles` ON `permissions`.`id` = `permissions_profiles`.`permission_id` WHERE `permissions_profiles`.`profile_id` = 185443385
  ↳ app/models/ability.rb:10:in `block in initialize'
  StockItem Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `stock_items`.* FROM `stock_items` WHERE `stock_items`.`id` = 747718251 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/stock_items_controller.rb:104:in `part_tag'
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'test.com' LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/stock_items_controller.rb:105:in `part_tag'
Started GET "/stock_items/502393374/part_tag?&token=ccc" for ::1 at 2020-11-09 19:25:12 -0500
Processing by StockItemsController#part_tag as HTML
  Parameters: {"token"=>"ccc", "stock_item_id"=>"502393374"}
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'abc.com' LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/concerns/authentication.rb:58:in `in_development_mode?'
  Profile Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `profiles`.* FROM `profiles` WHERE `profiles`.`id` = 185443385 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/models/ability.rb:10:in `block in initialize'
  Permission Load (1.4ms)  SELECT DISTINCT `permissions`.* FROM `permissions` INNER JOIN `permissions_profiles` ON `permissions`.`id` = `permissions_profiles`.`permission_id` WHERE `permissions_profiles`.`profile_id` = 185443385
  ↳ app/models/ability.rb:10:in `block in initialize'

  StockItem Load (1.1ms)  SELECT `stock_items`.* FROM `stock_items` WHERE `stock_items`.`id` = 502393374 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/stock_items_controller.rb:104:in `part_tag'
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'test.com' LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/stock_items_controller.rb:105:in `part_tag'
  Rendering layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering stock_items/part_tag.html.erb within layouts/application
  Product Load (1.6ms)  SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` WHERE `products`.`id` = 792659304 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/stock_items/_serviceable_part_tag.html.erb:10
  Certificate Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `certificates`.* FROM `certificates` WHERE `certificates`.`stock_item_id` = 502393374
  ↳ app/views/stock_items/_serviceable_part_tag.html.erb:60
  Transfer Load (1.7ms)  SELECT `transfers`.* FROM `transfers` WHERE `transfers`.`id` = 273907479 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/stock_items/_serviceable_part_tag.html.erb:71
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 207907133 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/stock_items/_serviceable_part_tag.html.erb:71
  Rendered stock_items/_serviceable_part_tag.html.erb (Duration: 39.2ms | Allocations: 7894)
  Rendered stock_items/_unserviceable_part_tag.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 35)
  Rendered stock_items/part_tag.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 46.1ms | Allocations: 10204)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered layouts/_nav_bar_common_option.html.erb (Duration: 14.0ms | Allocations: 281)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (Duration: 32.5ms | Allocations: 443)
  Rendered layouts/_nav_bar_common_option.html.erb (Duration: 0.6ms | Allocations: 276)
  Rendered layouts/_focused_object_header.html.erb (Duration: 1.6ms | Allocations: 422)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 51)
  Rendered layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 407.8ms | Allocations: 142784)
Completed 200 OK in 458ms (Views: 405.1ms | ActiveRecord: 11.1ms | Allocations: 151063)


Started GET "/stock_items/747718251/part_tag?&token=cccc" for ::1 at 2020-11-09 19:25:14 -0500
Processing by StockItemsController#part_tag as HTML
  Parameters: {"token"=>"ccc", "stock_item_id"=>"747718251"}
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'test.com' LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/concerns/authentication.rb:58:in `in_development_mode?'
  Profile Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `profiles`.* FROM `profiles` WHERE `profiles`.`id` = 185443385 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/models/ability.rb:10:in `block in initialize'
  Permission Load (1.0ms)  SELECT DISTINCT `permissions`.* FROM `permissions` INNER JOIN `permissions_profiles` ON `permissions`.`id` = `permissions_profiles`.`permission_id` WHERE `permissions_profiles`.`profile_id` = 185443385
  ↳ app/models/ability.rb:10:in `block in initialize'
  StockItem Load (0.9ms)  SELECT `stock_items`.* FROM `stock_items` WHERE `stock_items`.`id` = 747718251 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/stock_items_controller.rb:104:in `part_tag'
  User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'test.com' LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/stock_items_controller.rb:105:in `part_tag'
  Rendering layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering stock_items/part_tag.html.erb within layouts/application
  Product Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` WHERE `products`.`id` = 792659304 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/stock_items/_serviceable_part_tag.html.erb:10
  Certificate Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `certificates`.* FROM `certificates` WHERE `certificates`.`stock_item_id` = 747718251
  ↳ app/views/stock_items/_serviceable_part_tag.html.erb:60
  Transfer Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `transfers`.* FROM `transfers` WHERE `transfers`.`id` = 1026987850 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/stock_items/_serviceable_part_tag.html.erb:71
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 207907133 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/stock_items/_serviceable_part_tag.html.erb:71
  Rendered stock_items/_serviceable_part_tag.html.erb (Duration: 22.2ms | Allocations: 7229)
  Rendered stock_items/_unserviceable_part_tag.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 35)
  Rendered stock_items/part_tag.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 30.8ms | Allocations: 10908)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered layouts/_nav_bar_common_option.html.erb (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 281)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (Duration: 0.9ms | Allocations: 479)
  Rendered layouts/_nav_bar_common_option.html.erb (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 276)
  Rendered layouts/_focused_object_header.html.erb (Duration: 0.6ms | Allocations: 422)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 51)
  Rendered layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 283.9ms | Allocations: 136084)
Completed 200 OK in 328ms (Views: 281.3ms | ActiveRecord: 8.9ms | Allocations: 144078)


  **Rendering text template
  Rendered text template (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 1)
Sent data Serviceable_JBAEA00969_11-09-2020.pdf (2.1ms)**
Completed 200 OK in 6688ms (Views: 1.8ms | ActiveRecord: 4.7ms | Allocations: 2706188)


  Rendering text template
  Rendered text template (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 1)
Sent data Serviceable_JBAEA00967_11-09-2020.pdf (1.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6596ms (Views: 1.1ms | ActiveRecord: 3.9ms | Allocations: 2582540)
```

Comment: Downloading a file is no different from loading an HTML document. From the browser's point of view, it is a GET request to a resource that happens to return a PDF. What happens when you link on multiple "normal HTML" links at the same time? Exactly the same as you described, only the last page is shown. This behavior is expected and is the default behavior browsers handling links.

Comment: Is there any solution to tackle this?

Comment: There is nothing you can do or configure in Ruby to makes this work. IMO the only option is a right-click and choosing _open in new tap/window_. Or some Javascript that basically does the same.

Comment: Is it possible to add loader/spinner icon once a user click on the link to download , so that user will not be able to click on other links parallely till the first download is complete? I tried to do it but couldn't get around with it. I am using turbolinks and it will not get triggered for link click.